# Javascript date format today Asia GMT+8

Tags: javascript

In my country, today is `12/15/2022`, I'm from Asia which is gmt+8.

Basically I want my date to be `2022-12-15T00:00:00.000Z` instead of showing `2022-12-14T16:00:00.000Z.`

here is the code:

```js
const today = new Date().toLocaleDateString();
console.log(new Date(today));
```

But I really want it to be exact like this

```
2022-12-15T00:00:00.000Z
```

is it possible without using logic "add +8 hours"?

Comment: are you allowed libraries like `moment.js`. I suggest

Comment: Hi @StacksQueue, I have tried it but I can't get my desired output

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One way is to run your code in UTC zone so that you don't accidentally create dates in different time zones. You can set `TZ='UTC'` environment variable for this.

Otherwise you can create the date like this.

```js
const today = new Date().setUTCHours(0, 0, 0, 0); // note 'today' is a number now
> console.log(new Date(today))
2022-12-15T00:00:00.000Z
```

Answer (score 2):

you can force your time zone like this

```
console.log(new Date(new Date().toLocaleDateString('en', {timeZone: 'Asia/Hong_Kong'})))
```

Edit:
changed toLocaleString to toLocaleDateString
this should meet your needs now

Comment: Hi @Zack Heisenberg, thankyou for this. But I got "2022-12-15T06:04:32.000Z" what i want is 2022-12-15T00:00:00.000Z

Comment: Ah okay i will edit the code accordingly

Answer (score 0):

You can first convert the date to a local date string, then parse the year, month and day from it to construct the local ISO zero date string:

```js
const localDate = new Date().toLocaleDateString('en', {timeZone: 'Asia/Hong_Kong'});
console.log('localDate:', localDate);
let m = localDate.match(/(\d+)\/(\d+)\/(\d+)/);
let localZero = m[3] + '-' + m[1] + '-' + m[2] + 'T00:00:00.000Z';
console.log('localZero:', localZero);
```

Output:

```
localDate: 12/15/2022
localZero: 2022-12-15T00:00:00.000Z
```